# Can Artificial Intelligence be used to mine ethereum faster?

Tags: blockchain, mining, ethminer

Can Artificial Intelligence algorithm be used to improve hit rate of mining ethereum?

Answer (score 3):

Very unlikely. Machine learning is based on finding patterns in data, the very assumption of a good hashing function is that you gain no information about the data A seeing the hash of A nor you gain information about B knowing the hash of A and the hash of A + B. Therefore in theory you can not predict the output from unseen data. That said, is it "possible" that such a pattern exists after a highly non-linear transformation that we do not know yet.

Hope this helps